# Getting "Error registering COM+ Application"

Tags: registry, windows-installer, com+, component-services

I have a COM+ application that i am trying to install manually by double clicking on the .msi file but it gives error and fails to install the COM+ application.

It doesn't create any entry in Component Services as well due to this error.

I tried searching in registry as well but could find any entry with the COM+ application name.

How do i resolve this issue? I need to install this COM+ application on my server.

I have added screenshot of the error for reference.

[image]

Comment: Do you have previous versions of that application running on the box already?

Comment: It used to work earlier but now any version doesn't work

Comment: Can we see the actual MSI or is it internal use only or sensitive somehow? Please be sure to check properly - [MSI files can contain hidden credentials and sensitive data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48311010/how-do-i-avoid-distributing-sensitive-information-in-my-msi-by-accident). Eyeball it in Orca - table by table? (see link)

Comment: Maybe a PowerShell script could be used to set up your instances? I haven't tried, but I know MSI has problems with COM+.

Comment: Just checking to see if this has been resolved?

Comment: Yup, the issue was resolved when i installed the installer which during the installation installs the COM msi. The installer was able to install the COM successfully and after that i tried uninstalling the COM and it got uninstalled successfully but i could not found what exactly was the solution because in Installer as well i have used Cmd line to install the COM but when i tried to install the COM through command line manually it failed.

Comment: The MSI might return an error code that makes it roll back. A log file would help. See info below. Do you know what tool was used to create the MSI?

Answer (score 1):

***Admin Rights***: First of all, are you running the MSI with admin rights? Try launching from an elevated **`cmd.exe`** to be sure. COM+ MSI files can be exported from the Component Services applet - and they are then legendary poor quality. Here is a mock-up command line you can try:

```
msiexec.exe /i "Setup.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\log.log" /qn ALLUSERS=1
```

---

***Logging***: Secondly, please [**try to log the installation**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm) to see what it says in there. The above command line already implements logging, but here are more details on logging and interpreting the log file:

- [Event logging, etc...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983606/visual-studio-installer-fails-on-aspnetdiagnosticpack-msi/49987350#49987350)
- [Interpreting MSI log files, etc...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026782/website-is-not-getting-created-in-iis-limited-edition-of-installshield/49028367#49028367)

---

***Component Services***: You can also try to open **`Component Services`** and launch the MSI from there. I don't have a suitable MSI to test with at the moment. Providing some steps to get you going:

- ***Launch***: **`%windir%\system32\comexp.msc`** (<kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + Tap <kbd>R</kbd> + Type **`comexp.msc`** + <kbd>OK</kbd>)
- ***Locate***: **`Component Services`** **`=>`** **`Computers`** **`=>`** **`My Computer`** **`=>`** **`COM+ Applications`**
- Right Click **`"COM+ Applications"`** **`=>`** **`New`** **`=>`** **`Program`** **`=>`** **`Next`** **`=>`** **`Install pre-built program`** **`=>`** **`Browse to MSI`**

If you have the component installed on another computer you might be able to export a new MSI to use on your other computers. I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am trying to install the COM+ application as an administrator. I tried executing the msi using the command provided by you above and in the log it is saying that the " WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\COMPlus Applications\{27C788E4-D937-4B92-B0FC-48C76D2F40CC}\ReportingReconOLESvr.dll' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0)."

Comment: The log file also had this error i it "and also it is logging this error as well "Error 2945:  Installation of ComPlus App C:\Program Files (x86)\COMPlus Applications\{27C788E4-D937-4B92-B0FC-48C76D2F40CC}\APLDDFD.tmp failed with error -2146368511."

Comment: I tried from the Component services as well as per the steps provided by you but no success, it failed by poping up an error message saying "The DLL could not be loaded. Check to make sure all required application runtime files and other dependent dlls are available in the components DLL's directory or the system path."

Comment: For the record: COM+ deployment is a legendary source of problems. Fragile and poorly documented. Is this an MSI that is third party or is it "home grown"? It would be easier to take a look at it. WIN64DUALFOLDERS has to do with the resolution of the `%ProgramFiles%` folder and 32/64-bit issues. Does the MSI install on clean virtuals? Or on other computers? Is the application 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Yes, it is home grown. It used to work on all the VM's but when it was installed on already installed COM+ application after that i started facing this issue. Even after uninstalling the COM.

Comment: Hmm, from experience it might be easier to configure your components manually in **`Component Services`** so they run properly and then export a new MSI? Or even just configure all applications manually on all boxes if you got only a few boxes to deploy to? Just in the interest of getting things done. I have always had COM+ problems like these every time I have touched the technology. **WiX** has some nice COM+ features, but I have never had the time to test them. Honestly **Installshield** never worked for me, and **Advanced Installer** I haven't really tried with real COM+ components.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a COM+ application proxy in Windows 10. Edited the Registry, found any keys and values related to the application and deleted them all. Magically, the MSI then installed normally.